# GraphX create edges and vertices from csv

Tags: graph, rdd, spark-graphx

I have a csv file with flight information:

```
10397,ATL,GA,10135,ABE,PA,692,188
10397,ATL,GA,10135,ABE,PA,692,142
10434,AVP,PA,10135,ABE,PA,50,65
...
```

Columns are as follows: `ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN,ORIGIN_STATE_ABR,DEST_AIRPORT_ID,DEST,DEST_STATE_ABR,DISTANCE,TIME`

I want to create edge and vertex rdds from these.
(the data is stored in`filtflights.csv`)
for edge I wrote the following: 
`val flighttime:RDD[Edge[Integer]] = sc.textFile("filtflights.csv").map {line =>
      val row = line.split(",")
      Edge(row(0).toInt, row(3).toInt, row(7).toInt)
    }`
But I am not sure about vertexes.
From what I've gathered I can create a class called `Airport` for example, and do the following:

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId,Airport)] = sc.textFile("filtflights.csv").map
```

but I am unsure as to how exactly set VertexId to be `ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID` of any given row (I live with the assumption that every node will be origin eventually so don't need to create vertices from the `DEST_AIRPORT_ID` column.)